# Where does pip get installed?

Tags: python-2.7, path, pip

Learning python and need to use pip to install a library, but I cannot in the world of me find out how to get it to work.

If I type `pip` in cmd I get 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

OK, trying to install it

```
python get-pip.py
```

Return: Requirement alredy up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages 
There is a directory named "pip" and "pip-8.1.2.dist-info" but neither of them includes pip.exe (should they not?)

Have tried to temporary set the path
`set path=%PATH%;c:\python27\lib\site-packages`
Still does not work..
I have tried to search for pip.exe everywhere in my computer but cannot find it.
What is the default path when I run python get-pip.py?

EDIT: OK so I actually found it now in `C:\Python27\Scripts` as it should..
I have done `set path=%PATH%;C:/Python27/Scripts`
If I go ahead and type `pip install help` the cmd seem to stop respond, there is a marker blinking and I have to close it using X.

I am really stuck, I am not familiar with this configuration. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Remove all other python path reference from the path variables and append this two python path at the end in the path variable:

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;
```